# PHP - regex to allow letters and numbers only

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have tried:

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]", $value)
```

but im doing something wrong i guess.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

### 1. Use PHP's inbuilt [ctype_alnum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php)

You dont need to use a regex for this, PHP has an inbuilt function `ctype_alnum` which will do this for you, and execute faster:

```
<?php
$strings = array('AbCd1zyZ9', 'foo!#$bar');
foreach ($strings as $testcase) {
    if (ctype_alnum($testcase)) {
        echo "The string $testcase consists of all letters or digits.\n";
    } else {
        echo "The string $testcase does not consist of all letters or digits.\n";
    }
}
?>
```

### 2. Alternatively, use a regex

If you desperately want to use a regex, you have a few options.

Firstly:

```
preg_match('/^[\w]+$/', $string);
```

`\w` includes more than alphanumeric (it includes underscore), but includes all
of `\d`.

Alternatively:

```
/^[a-zA-Z\d]+$/
```

Or even just:

```
/^[^\W_]+$/
```

Comment: `[\w\d]` is redundant - `\w` is enough since it already contains `\d`.

Comment: In the first example a `+` is missing, so it should be `'/^[\w]+$/'`.

Comment: Added the missing `+` quantifier.

Comment: `[\w]` is more simply expressed as `\w`.

Answer (score 27):

You left off the `/` (pattern delimiter) and `$` (match end string).

```
preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/", $value)
```

Comment: This solution is not working on Turkish language characters. Thank you

Answer (score 14):

- Missing end anchor $
- Missing multiplier
- Missing end delimiter

So it should fail anyway, but if it may work, it matches against just one digit at the beginning of the string.

```
/^[a-z0-9]+$/i
```

Answer (score 3):

As the OP said that he wants letters and numbers ONLY (no underscore!), one more way to have this in **php** regex is to use posix expressions:

```
/^[[:alnum:]]+$/
```

Note: This will not work in Java, JavaScript, Python, Ruby, .NET

Answer (score -2):

try this way .eregi("[^A-Za-z0-9.]", $value)

Comment: ereg/eregi are old functions. Use preg_match instead. Also, you should add the i identifier so letters are case insensitive.