# How to exclude special characters in a regular expression

Tags: php, regex, string, special-characters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - regex to allow letters and numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345621/php-regex-to-allow-letters-and-numbers-only)

I need a RegEx that matches `a-z`, `A-Z` and `0-9` strings. **Not** á, à, ð, ð, ü, ĉ, etc.
How can I accomplish this?

Comment: So many examples in the manual! http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 3):

Try that one for example:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Comment: Still matches á, é, ù,... for some reason :S

Comment: @John: Does `setlocale(LC_ALL, 'C');` fix it?

Comment: @JohnDoe: Doesn't for me: http://ideone.com/Lpeeh

Comment: @icktoofay that somehow made the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: @icktoofay: Can you explain what's happening here? I'm shocked that PHP would ignore a clearly defined character range. Is that the default behavior?

Comment: @Tim: No, I don't know why it does that. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use a character class to match a single character:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]
```

Apply quantifiers (*, +, whatever) as appropriate.