# PHP only letters, numbers, spaces remaining in string

Tags: php, string, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP - regex to allow letters and numbers only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345621/php-regex-to-allow-letters-and-numbers-only)

First sorry for my bad English.
I have question.

I have a string (it's only an example)

```
$string = 'on"c,e. //up!@#on$# a @#ti'][;me 2012';
```

What do I need to do, to make the string look like:

```
$string_after_clean_up = 'once upon a time 2012';
```

I need to remove all the symbols except letters/numbers and spaces.
I was trying with preg_mach() but I failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$string_after_clean_up = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9\s]/i", "", $string);`
`$string_after_clean_up = preg_replace("/\s\s+/", " ", $string_after_clean_up);`

Comment: i getting error.

 preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: Just use the `i` modifier only, don't need `g` there

Comment: Stupid me. Too much JavaScript in the recent past. I edited the answer.

Comment: Yeah... now i have another problem. When i remove all simbols (!@#$ and e.t.c.) in between words hangind 3 or 2 spaces...
exaple: 
word !@#$ another word
after removing
word      another word
how solve that?

Comment: Edited my answer to include a second line to replace the extra spaces.