# Check for letters, numbers and spaces?

Tags: php, forms, if-statement

I'm making a Full Name field and only want the user to be able to enter numbers, letters and spaces. How would that be done in an if statement?

Comment: Related, possibly a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4345621/2460971

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can go the opposite way and check if there are any *illegal* characters using, for instance:

```
if (preg_match("/[^a-z\\d ]/i", $input))
    // illegal input
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution,

```
if(preg_match('/[^\w\d ]/',$input)){
    //illegal input
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `\w` matches an underscore