# PHP Fetch data from string array

Tags: php

To Clarify I used **JSON.stringify(myArray)** from view
before I sent it to controller.

I have string array like following :

```
[
                [["\"1\"","\"1\""],["\"a\"","\"a\""]],
                [["\"2\"","\"2\""],["\"b\"","\"b\""],["\"c\"","\"c\""]],
                []
]
```

I want to fetch data by using foreach.

Like :

```
0- 1, 1 and a,a 
1- 2,2 and b,b and c,c 
2- null
```

I tried **string_data[0][0]** , it doesn't work.

And

```
foreach(string_data[0] as $value){
}
```

It also doesn't work.

Only string_data[0] works.

Comment: please make it more clear. the above string looks more like an array.

Comment: you can not use string in foreach

Comment: try `regex` : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345621/php-regex-to-allow-letters-and-numbers-only

Comment: Is this `string` or `json`?

Comment: I used json.stringfy from view. But when I received in controller it shows string.  @ata

Comment: Ok now you should use `json_decode(VARIABLE, true)` to convert `json` to a PHP array.

Comment: Yes you are right . Its working. @ata

Answer (score 1):

Solution is :

```
json_decode(VARIABLE, true)
```

Coz it(array) was sent from view as json.Stringfy. 
Php json decode function make it array again.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Answers with only code in them tend to get flagged for deletion as they are "low quality".  Please read the help section on answering questions then consider adding some commentary to your Answer.

Comment: Why is that the answer? What does it do? What is the meaning of the second parameter?

Comment: explanation given